# Getting ValueError when trying to get video (blob) object's metadata from GCS bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, bucket

When running this python script

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket_name')
blob1 = bucket.get_blob(blob)
print(blob1.name)
```

getting the following error:

```
ValueError: <Blob: bucket-name, /videos/batch1TestingVideo1/video1.mp4, 1600346932097827> 
could not be converted to unicode
```

All objects stored in the bucket are video files.

How to get metadata of stored video files in the bucket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys I figured out the problem

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket_name')
blob1 = bucket.get_blob(blob.name)
print(blob1.name)
```

instead of blob object, I should have passed blob.name to get metadata of that object